# Crop Circles expansion - Do players HAVE to place a meeple?

Tags: carcassonne

In the Crop Circles expansion the rules for choosing Option A (placing additional meeples) was ambiguous.

For option B, it's quite clear that everybody, starting at the active player's left, must remove a meeple of the type denoted by the crop circle.

However, it wasn't clear on option A, whether the players MUST place an additional meeple, or whether they could choose not to.

Answer (score 2):

The [crop circle rules](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Carcassonne_Mini_Crop_Circles.pdf) are slightly ambiguous but my reading of option A is that all players MAY place an extra follower on a tile they have a follower, but if they do it MUST be with a follower of the same type.

I think it reads better if you put the rules together rather than separating them.

He then decides for every player, starting with the player to his left, if:
A) they can place another follower on a tile where they already have a follower
of the type designated by the crop circle.... the player must place the new follower with another one of his followers of the same type (a farmer with a farmer, a thief with a thief, a knight with a knight).